# Upgrad netty 3.2.5 -> 3.6.6, receiving message fails

Tags: netty

I am trying to upgrad netty version 3.2.5 to 3.6.6. One of my tests fails with version 3.5.9 and works with 3.5.8. It’s the same test output is below. For some reason the response of the server is not received.

Message sending is triggered by the timeout of the idle handler. Server log (below) looks always the same. I can’t find any issue in github. Do I miss something? Thx! joël

**ChannelPipelineFactory**

```
public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline();
            // logging handler
            pipeline.addLast("LOGGER", new LoggingHandler());
            // responsible for observing idle timeout - Netty
            pipeline.addLast("idleTimeout", new NettyIdleHandler(this.context, this.timer, 0, 0, this.context.getIdleTimeoutSeconds()));
            // responsible for reading until SCMP frame is complete
            pipeline.addLast("framer", new NettySCMPFrameDecoder());
            // executer to run NettyTcpRequesterResponseHandler in own thread
            pipeline.addLast("executor", new ExecutionHandler(AppContext.getSCWorkerThreadPool()));
            // responsible for handle response - Stabilit
            pipeline.addLast("requesterResponseHandler", new NettyTcpRequesterResponseHandler());
            return pipeline;
}
```

**3.2.5.Final (currently used)**

```
2013-06-27 15:13:27.908+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff] OPEN    
2013-06-27 15:13:27.918+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff] CONNECT: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:13:27.968+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:1365    
2013-06-27 15:13:27.968+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CONNECTED: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:13:28.930+0200 [Hashed wheel timer #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITE: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22) - (HEXDUMP: 4b5251203030303030303020303030303020312e320a)    
2013-06-27 15:13:28.960+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITTEN_AMOUNT: 22    
2013-06-27 15:13:28.970+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] RECEIVED: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22) - (HEXDUMP: 4b5253203030303030303020303030303020312e320a)    
2013-06-27 15:13:29.380+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECT    
2013-06-27 15:13:29.380+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECTED    
2013-06-27 15:13:29.380+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] UNBOUND    
2013-06-27 15:13:29.380+0200 [New I/O client worker #1-1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSED    
2013-06-27 15:13:29.390+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:39) - [id: 0x001cdeff, /127.0.0.1:1365 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSE
```

**3.5.8.Final (still working)**

```
2013-06-27 15:02:38.388+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e] OPEN    
2013-06-27 15:02:38.388+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e] CONNECT: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:02:38.418+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:1349    
2013-06-27 15:02:38.418+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CONNECTED: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.440+0200 [Hashed wheel timer #2] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITE: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 4b 52 51 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 30 30 |KRQ 0000000 0000|
|00000010| 30 20 31 2e 32 0a                               |0 1.2.          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.440+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITTEN_AMOUNT: 22    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.460+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] RECEIVED: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 4b 52 53 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 30 30 |KRS 0000000 0000|
|00000010| 30 20 31 2e 32 0a                               |0 1.2.          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.820+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECT    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.830+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECTED    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.830+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] UNBOUND    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.830+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSED    
2013-06-27 15:02:39.830+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x33e9778e, /127.0.0.1:1349 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSE
```

**3.5.9.Final (test fails)**

```
2013-06-27 15:17:00.984+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde] OPEN    
2013-06-27 15:17:00.995+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde] CONNECT: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:17:01.015+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:4332    
2013-06-27 15:17:01.015+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CONNECTED: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.016+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITE: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 4b 52 51 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 30 30 |KRQ 0000000 0000|
|00000010| 30 20 31 2e 32 0a                               |0 1.2.          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.016+0200 [New I/O  worker #1] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] WRITTEN_AMOUNT: 22
```

***?????***

```
2013-06-27 15:17:02.417+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 => localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECT    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.427+0200 [main] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0xacb50bde, /127.0.0.1:4332 :> localhost/127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSE
```

**Server log (3.5.9.Final)**

```
2013-06-27 15:17:01.005+0200 [New I/O server boss #2 ([id: 0x08e17840, /127.0.0.1:9000])] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] OPEN    
2013-06-27 15:17:01.005+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] BOUND: /127.0.0.1:9000    
2013-06-27 15:17:01.005+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] CONNECTED: /127.0.0.1:4332    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.026+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] RECEIVED: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 4b 52 51 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 30 30 |KRQ 0000000 0000|
|00000010| 30 20 31 2e 32 0a                               |0 1.2.          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.036+0200 [SC_WORKER thread-3] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] WRITE: BigEndianHeapChannelBuffer(ridx=0, widx=22, cap=22)
         +-------------------------------------------------+
         |  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  b  c  d  e  f |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|00000000| 4b 52 53 20 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 20 30 30 30 30 |KRS 0000000 0000|
|00000010| 30 20 31 2e 32 0a                               |0 1.2.          |
+--------+-------------------------------------------------+----------------+    
2013-06-27 15:17:02.036+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, /127.0.0.1:4332 => /127.0.0.1:9000] WRITTEN_AMOUNT: 22
2013-06-27 15:17:02.417+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, localhost/127.0.0.1:4332 :> /127.0.0.1:9000] DISCONNECTED
2013-06-27 15:17:02.417+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, localhost/127.0.0.1:4332 :> /127.0.0.1:9000] UNBOUND
2013-06-27 15:17:02.417+0200 [New I/O  worker #431] DEBUG (org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler:33) - [id: 0x0a003af2, localhost/127.0.0.1:4332 :> /127.0.0.1:9000] CLOSED
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem found.
Well blocking the thread is a bad idea :/. Running the idle procedure in a new thread solves the problem.
Guess its because the IdleStateEvent is now handled by the worker thread since it has been changed in 3.5.9 according to:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/641
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/NETTY-362

Why is the idleStateEvent not handed over to one of my own worker threads specified in the pipeline as executor "ExecutionHandler"? Or is my conf wrong? thx!